# In AngularJS, how to Scale Text to Fit in Fixed Div?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to place text inside a div that has a fixed width and height, the issue is that the text varies from time to time so for example sometimes inside the div, it will appear : MEDITERRANEAN and sometimes AMERICAN. I issue is that I don't know how texts of different sizes can fit inside the div and change it font size accurately.

After googling, I found this jQuery plugin : http://danielhoffmann.github.io/jquery-bigtext/
but what I need is how to do it in AngularJS.

Any information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution on AngularJS, called ng-fi-text

Here is it :

http://leandropio.github.io/ng-fi-text/

Good Luck !!